# Why are my directories nested?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that takes a .csv file and writes each row to an xml file in a newly created directory (1 xml file in each directory). It works, but my directories come out nested. How can I modify this so they are not nested?

```
import os, csv

metadata = csv.reader(open('metadata.csv'))

row_num = 0
for row in metadata:
    if row_num == 0:
        tags = row
    else:
        os.makedirs('submission-%d' % row_num)
        os.chdir('submission-%d' % row_num)
        out_file = open('metadata-xml-%d.xml' % row_num, 'w')
        out_file.write('<submissionData>' + '\n')
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            out_file.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + '\n')
        out_file.write('</submissionData>')
        print(file=out_file)
    row_num +=1

out_file.close()
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you added a `tags = next(metadata)` right _before_ the `for` loop, you would no longer need the `if row_num == 0:` & `else` within it. You also wouldn't need the `row_num` variable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lenik mentioned, you don't need to change into subdirectories. If you replace your `else:` block with the following code, your directories will not be nested and will be created the way you expect:

```
else:
    dir_name = 'submission-%d' % row_num
    os.makedirs(dir_name)
    file_name = os.path.join(dir_name, 'metadata-xml-%d.xml' % row_num)
    out_file = open(file_name, 'w')
    out_file.write('<submissionData>' + '\n')
    for i in range(len(tags)):
        out_file.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + '\n')
    out_file.write('</submissionData>')
    print(file=out_file)
```

Make sure you indent this code properly, otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You descend into a directory with `os.chdir` before creating a new one. Add `os.chdir("..")` at the end of the `else` branch:

```
else:
    os.makedirs('submission-%d' % row_num)
    os.chdir('submission-%d' % row_num)
    # Do your stuff, close the file
    print(file=out_file)
    os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: Where exactly? I just tried moving that line around, but it's still not working like I want it to.

Comment: Just as I said, at the end of the `else` branch. It has only one end, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, I just tried that and it didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Works for me. Make sure that you indented it correctly (it must be a part of the `else` branch). By the way, `out_file.close()` should be in the loop, not after it.

Comment: Thanks (obviously new to python). Can you share a screenshot? I must be doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a program to behave like a human, don't use `chdir()`:

```
folder = 'submission-%d' % row_num
name = os.path.join( folder, 'metadata-xml-%d.xml' % row_num)
out_file = open( name, 'w')
```

is much simpler and easier to understand. And you don't need to worry about walking around your subfolders anymore.